# How should I unit-test a long function?

Tags: java, unit-testing

If  i have a long method of code which gathers data from 2 or 3 difference sources and returns a result. How can I refactor it so that it is more unit-testable? This method is a webservice and I want to make one call from client code to gather all the data.

I can refactor some portions out into smaller methods which will be more testable. But the current method will still be calling those 5 methods and will remain less testable. Assuming Java as programming language, is there a pattern for making such code testable?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a very common testing problem, and the most common solution I come across for this is to separate the sourcing of data from the code which uses the data using dependency injection. This not only supports good testing, but is generally a good strategy when working with external data sources (good segregation of responsibilities, isolates the integration point, promotes code reuse being some reasons for this).

The changes you need to make go something like:

- For each data source, create an interface to define how data from that source is accessed, and then factor out the code which returns the data into a separate class which implements this.
- Dependency inject the data source into the class containing your 'long' function.
- For unit testing, inject a mock implementation of each data source.

Here is some code examples showing what this would look like - note that this code is merely illustrative of the pattern, you will need some more sensible names for things. It would be worth studying this pattern and learning more about dependency injection & mocking - two of the most powerful weapons in the unit testers armory.

**Data Sources**

```
public interface DataSourceOne {
    public Data getData();
}

public class DataSourceOneImpl implements DataSourceOne {
    public Data getData() {
        ...
        return data;
    }
}

public interface DataSourceTwo {
    public Data getData();
}

public class DataSourceTwoImpl implements DataSourceTwo {
    public Data getData() {
        ...
        return data;
    }
}
```

**Class with Long Method**

```
public class ClassWithLongMethod {
    private DataSourceOne dataSourceOne;
    private DataSourceTwo dataSourceTwo;

    public ClassWithLongMethod(DataSourceOne dataSourceOne,
                               DataSourceTwo dataSourceTwo) {
        this.dataSourceOne = dataSourceOne;
        this.dataSourceTwo = dataSourceTwo;
    }

    public Result longMethod() {
        someData = dataSourceOne.getData();
        someMoreData = dataSourceTwo.getData();
        ...
        return result;
    }
}
```

**Unit Test**

```
import org.junit.Test;

import static org.mockito.Mockito.mock;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.when;

public class ClassWithLongMethodTest {

    @Test
    public void testLongMethod() {

        // Create mocked data sources which return the data required by your test
        DataSourceOne dataSourceOne = mock(DataSourceOne.class);
        when(dataSourceOne.getData()).thenReturn(...);
        DataSourceTwo dataSourceTwo = mock(DataSourceTwo.class);
        when(dataSourceTwo.getData()).thenReturn(...);

        // Create the object under test using the mocked data sources
        ClassWithLongMethod sut = new ClassWithLongMethod(dataSourceOne,
                                                          dataSourceTwo);

        // Now you can unit test the long method in isolation from it's dependencies
        Result result = sut.longMethod();

        // Assertions on result
        ...
    }
}
```

*Please forgive (and correct) any syntactic mistakes, I don't write much java these days.*

Answer (score 0):

The test for the "big" method will look like integration test where the smaller methods can be mocked.

If you can separate the "big" method into five isolated methods, then the "big" method could be further partitioned into semantically-/contextually-meaningful groups of the isolated methods.

Then you can mock the larger groupings of isolated methods for the "big" method.

Comment: But aren't you then introducing complexity? If a function isn't used more than 2 or 3 times, isn't it better if it's inline, to make it more simple?

Comment: @JakeZieve It totally depends. You're trading one kind of complexity for another--when it's all in one method you have higher cyclomatic complexity, it's harder to reason about, and harder to test. I prefer tasty, bite-sized chunks of simplicity that I can compose. Refactoring isn't just for re-use, it's to enhance your ability to reason about it. I'd argue most function extractions are (initially) about re-use, but about separating concerns and flattening levels of abstraction in single methods.

Comment: But you aren't flattening levels of abstraction, you're introducing abstraction, right? If I refactor out a method to 3 different methods in 3 different files, thats 2 extra paths that I must take to reason about the original method. Isn't that increasing the cyclomatic complexity? Is "harder to reason about"  just subjective? You still have to read the same code, its just in 3 separate places instead of 1. Plus, you had to think up a nice name for that function, doesn't that add overhead? A simple comment explaining what a block of logic block does and why, could achieve the same result, imo.

Comment: @JakeZieve All methods should operate at a single level of abstraction. If you're able to extract multiple methods from a single method it's unlikely (at best) that was the case originally. I don't know why you're talking about files--Java doesn't allow dropping a method into a file. If you're abstracting to a class, and it makes sense to do so, it's because the original design was *missing* that class. But no, that doesn't increase cyclomatic complexity; at worst it keeps it the same.

Comment: @JakeZieve  And no, you don't *necessarily* have to read the same code--you only read code as far as you need to to understand what's happening. If you have a block of code you feel the need to comment then you're missing a chance to clarify it via code-only, which is the ultimate arbiter of functionality--not comments.

Comment: All of the time we're reading code is when something goes wrong, we need to extend a functionality, or we need to refactor something (maybe all at once). Having multiple places to look complicates things. I'm not saying never create separate methods, just its not always better. A block comment can be way more descriptive than a name /* Do this one thing, because this horrible edge case, blah blah */ is easier to read than doThisOneThingBecauseHorribleEdgeCaseBlahBlah() in my opinion.

Comment: @JakeZieve You'll find you're in a small minority on keeping methods long, but OK. Of course a larger comment can be e descriptive than a name-I'm saying if you need a long comment then you need a refactoring.